# Dialogfow webhook using static response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm designing a Google Actions webhook.  I want to use the pre-defined static response for most requests, but in some situations, I want to return a 'simple response' to the user.

I've read that if my webhook does not return a response, then the static response will be used, but the webhook response format requires a 'Richresponse'.  How can I send a response that will cause the static response to be used?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the static responses that are defined in Dialogflow console, you can use the incoming property of the conversation object. here is the [document](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.incoming.html) explaining how it works.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm using the webhook format.  Is that documentation for the SDK?  What I receive is "queryResult": {}"fulfillmentText": "This is the static response for $variable."  So that shows me what the static response would be and my application can parrot it back in the http response.  That will work, but I was looking for a way to invoke the static response without having to send it back in the response.